# Where do I ask Cryptography questions?

Tags: discussion

I have a cryptography question and I am not sure if I should ask it on ServerFault or SuperUser. Generally, which would be the best site to ask most cryptographic question that do not pertain to the programming side of cryptography?

The Question: What is the difference between Arbitrary algorithms, Asynchronous algorithms, and Parallel algorithms?

Answer (score 11):

Perhaps our [Cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/) beta site is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks! That works very well. I never knew that SE site existed.

Comment: Security (http://security.stackexchange.com/) also has lots of crypto related questions.

Comment: @Zoredache True, but [security.se] is more practical and would kick a pure-math question like these over to [crypto.se] anyway.

Answer (score 7):

Okay, I asked the question on the Cryptography site and it was marked as off-topic. Someone there said to ask on the Computer Science site (http://cs.stackexchange.com). Thankfully they did not downvote the question. They nicely informed me and I moved the question.

After transferring the question between different StackExchange sites

Chain of Recommendation: ServerFault -> Cryptography Beta -> Computer Science -> Unix/Linux

I found the correct place and answer. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102836/asynchronous-and-parallel-algorithms-in-the-linux-kernel/